# questions on Poulet numbers and Fermat pseudoprimes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have found the following problems on Poulet numbers and Fermat Poulet numbers. I guess, I can have good explanation to complete my problems here.

I want to prove or disprove the following:

1. For any positive integer $k$, there exists infinitely many Poulet numbers of the form $(4^k-1)/3$.
2. For a prime $k > 3$, the number $(4^k-1)/3$ is Poulet number.
3. For any integer $n > 1$, the following formula generates infinitely many Fermat pseudoprimes to base $n$:

   $$(n^{nk+k+n-1}-1)/n^2 -1.$$

High regards,

Dr.MM

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - could you please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @MarkBennet! is my probelms are correct or not. If yes, how to prove it.

Comment: Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) tells us that a Poulet number is the same thing as a Fermat pseudoprime to base 2: that is, it's an integer $n$ such that $2^n \equiv 2 \bmod n$. It does appear to be true that $(4^p - 1)/3$ has this property for all primes $p$ with $5 \le p < 500$, so (2) (and hence (1)) are certainly plausible.

Comment: @David Loeffler!I need still more better explanation for all.

Comment: The 1st question, as currently stated, makes no sense. For any positive integer $k$, there is at most one Poulet number of the form $(4^k-1)/3$.

Comment: Come, don't be a Scrooge, @GerryMyerson! It's clear what he means.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, it wouldn't hurt for Dr.MM to edit so what's written and what's meant coincide. One of the distinguishing characteristics of Mathematics is that it's generally possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma 1**: If $k$ is any integer $\ge 2$ and $N = (4^k - 1)/3$, then $2^{2k} = 1 \bmod N$.

*Proof*: We have $2^{2k} - 1 = 4^k - 1 = 3N$, so $N \mid 2^{2k} - 1$. QED.

**Lemma 2**: If $k \ge 5$ is prime, then $(4^k - 1)/3 = 1 \bmod 2k$.

*Proof*: Since $k$ is prime, we have $4^k = 4 \bmod k$. Hence $4^k - 1 = 3 \bmod k$, and thus $(4^k - 1)/3 = 1 \bmod k$; the division by $3$ is valid since $3 \nmid k$. On the other hand, $(4^k - 1)/3$ is odd and hence $(4^k - 1)/3 = 1 \bmod 2$. Since $k$ is odd, this implies $(4^k - 1)/3 = 1 \bmod 2k$. QED.

**Theorem**: For any prime $k > 3$, the integer $N = (4^k - 1)/3$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base 2, i.e. $2^N = 2 \bmod N$.

*Proof*: We know that $N = 1 \bmod 2k$ by lemma 2, so we can write $N = 1 + 2ak$ for some integer $a$. Hence $2^N - 2 = 2^{1 + 2ak} - 2 = 2( (2^{2k})^a - 1)$. But we know $2^{2k} = 1 \bmod N$ by lemma 1, so $(2^{2k})^a = 1^a = 1 \bmod N$. Thus $2^N - 2 = 0 \bmod N$. QED.

This proves (2), and hence clearly also (1), since there are infinitely many primes! I'll leave you to think about (3) for yourself; you might like to see if the same methods give anything in this case.